# C# Linq return the first element of each group

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

What I try to achieve is the following: Filter the ProjektStatus with the where function, the group them by ProjektId. Order the group descending by StatusMonatJahr and then **take the first element of each group and return it.**

```
public IEnumerable<ProjektStatus> GetCurrentProjektStatus(Func<ProjektStatus, bool> where)
{
    return this.db.ProjektStatus
        .Where(where)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProjektId)
        .Select(x => 
             x.OrderByDescending(y => y.StatusMonatJahr))
        .First();
}
```

Unfortunately, with this query I get the first whole group instead of the first element of each group.

What do I have to change to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to move the `First` inside of the `Select` so it's applied to the ordered group instead of the collection of groups.  `.Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.StatusMonatJahr).First());`

Comment: oooh that makes sense! thank you it worked :-) if you add it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Comment: `OrderBy` plus `First` is a fairly expensive way to get the biggest item from a collection.  You might consider implementing a `MaxBy` method that just searches for the biggest item directly.

Comment: @PeterRuderman `MaxBy` doesn't exist in the BCL. For linq to object it may exist in MoreLinq. And in this case (Linq to entities) I suppose the expression will be optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should return the first element in each group, not the content of the first group.

```
public IEnumerable<ProjektStatus> GetCurrentProjektStatus(Func<ProjektStatus, bool> where)
{
    return this.db.ProjektStatus
                  .Where(where)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.ProjektId)
                  .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.StatusMonatJahr).First());
}
```

Some remarks :

- Language keyword should be avoided as variable name. Here it's about the `where` parameter. `whereFunc` is a good name.
- The `GroupBy`, `Select`, `OrderByDescending` *operations* can be done remotely (server side), for that they should be called first. An other option is to do everything remotely, for that, the type of the `whereFunc` should be `Expression<Func<ProjectStatus, bool>>`.
- Personal opinion: you should prefer to code in English, if your company doesn't do it, I feel bad for you.

Here is the result :

```
public IEnumerable<ProjectStatus> GetCurrentProjectStatuses(Func<ProjectStatus, bool> whereFunc)
{
    return ProjectStatuses
        .GroupBy(s => s.ProjectId)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.MonthAndYear).First())
        .AsEnumerable()   // From now on the execution is done locally 
        .Where(whereFunc);
}
```